# Require the used parts of 3rd party libraries

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I'm aware of the new [Tree Shaking](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html) feature.  I have this enabled.  I read online that you can explicitly require pieces of large frameworks such as lodash.  The [example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/658) I saw said do this in webpack.prod.config:

`const _each = require('lodash-node/modern/collections/forEach');`

A.  Is this still useful for those that have tree shaking?
B.  Can you provide a more complete example of using this in webpack?  I don't see the point of adding this line to the top of webpack.  How does this change the build?